# Python gRPC shopping cart service

Tags: python, server, e-commerce, client, grpc

The `.proto` file is as below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package bamboo;

// -----------------Cart service-----------------

service CartService {
    rpc AddItem(AddItemRequest) returns (Empty) {}
    rpc GetCart(GetCartRequest) returns (Cart) {}
    rpc EmptyCart(EmptyCartRequest) returns (Empty) {}
}

message CartItem {
    string product_id = 1;
    int32  quantity = 2;
}

message AddItemRequest {
    string user_id = 1;
    CartItem item = 2;
}

message EmptyCartRequest {
    string user_id = 1;
}

message GetCartRequest {
    string user_id = 1;
}

message Cart {
    string user_id = 1;
    repeated CartItem items = 2;
}

message Empty {}
```

And I have a `Cart` service on gRPC that is as simple as below:

```
from grpczoo import bamboo_pb2_grpc, bamboo_pb2
from concurrent import futures
import grpc
import time


class CartService(bamboo_pb2_grpc.CartServiceServicer):
    def AddItem(self, request, context):
        print(request.user_id, request.item)
        return bamboo_pb2.Empty()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('127.0.0.1')
    cart_stub = bamboo_pb2_grpc.CartServiceStub(channel)

    # create gRPC server
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

    # add class to gRPC server
    service = CartService()
    bamboo_pb2_grpc.add_CartServiceServicer_to_server(service, server)

    # start server
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:9000')
    server.start()

    # keep alive
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(10000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            server.stop(0)
```

Let's assume that starting a service like above seems good when you have 40 services (We can create a base class for starting a service)

The most annoying part of the system is where I have to initiate a client when I need to send a RPC call to a service (here cart service):

```
import grpc

# set up server stub
from grpczoo import bamboo_pb2_grpc, bamboo_pb2

channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:9000')
stub = bamboo_pb2_grpc.CartServiceStub(channel)
# form request
request = bamboo_pb2.AddItemRequest(user_id="123", item={'product_id': '21', 'quantity': 2})

# make call to server
response = stub.AddItem(request)
print(response)
```

As you can see for a simple RPC call like above I have to open channel to that service and form a request and then call the remote method `AddItem`. In a real world micro-service project I have to call at least 5 different methods and for each I have to create a channel and for the request and so on.

**The question is** how should I manage RPC calls to different methods when project gets bigger and I have 20 to 50 different services? The above code does not seems maintainable at all. How do you handle such cases?

Comment: You should change your title according to [*Titling your question*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

### Keep-alive

Your `sleep` method is curious. There are alternates here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170251/how-to-run-the-python-program-forever

but those are generic to Python; there is a better option for [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/):

> In this case, you can call `server.wait_for_termination()` to cleanly block the calling thread until the server terminates.

### Stopping

You should not only call it on `KeyboardInterrupt`; you should put it in a `finally`:

```
    server.start()
    try:
        # ...
    finally:
        server.stop(0)
```

This way, the server will be stopped if the user breaks with Ctrl+C, or if there is any other exception. However, I doubt it's necessary to call this at all if you use `wait_for_termination`.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with gRPC client in C#. There you can initialize the client in the constructor with no additional code needed on request. It should be the same in Python.

```
public MyClient(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger < MyClient > logger) {
 _logger = logger;
 _configuration = configuration;
 var config = _configuration.GetGrpcConfigObject(...);
 var myConfig = config.HostName + ":" + config.Port;
 _channel = new Channel(myConfig, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
 _client = new ServiceClient(_channel);
}

public async Task <IEnumerable<Model.Permission>> GetPermissions() {
 IEnumerable <Model.Permission> resultList = null;
 try {
   PermissionResponse response = await _client.GetPermissionsAsync(new Empty());
  resultList = _mapper.Map <IEnumerable <Permission > , IEnumerable <Model.Permission >> (response.PermissionList);

 } catch (Exception ex) {
  _logger.LogError($ "BatchSave failed:{ex}");
 }
 return resultList;
}
```